# ASP.NET MVC - Dropdown - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

MenuType definiation:

```
 public string Code { get; set; } 
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

ASP.NET MVC 5

I have searched and read before I'm posting my question here,

I'm trying to LOAD the data in the asp.net mvc dropdownlist why is that so complicated?

//controller

```
public class ClientController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       List<MenuType> ctypelist = db.ContractTypes.OrderBy(x => x.TypeOfContract).ToList();

       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = new SelectList(ctypelist.ToList());
       ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract = list;
       return View();
    }

}
```

//html

```
@model myapp.Models.Client


@Html.DropDownList("Codes", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract , new { style = "max-width: 600px;" })%>
```

Comment: What is your definition of MenuType?  And is ContractTypes of type MenuType?

Comment: With your reputation, I would think you would understand how to edit your question...  code does not belong in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's complicated is that you can't seem to decide which type you're using...

First you have a `List<MenuType>` (I assume `ContractTypes` is actually of type `MenuType`?) Then you create a `SelectList`, passing the `List<MenuType>` to it, which implies that `MenuType` must have at least two properties, one called `Text` and one called `Value`.  If not, you will have to specify the `Text` and `Value` property names in the `SelectList` constructor parameters.

After that, for some reason you convert it to a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, then you assign that to a ViewBag item and call your View.  So, at this point, your ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Next, in your View, you for some reason define an `@model` depite not passing any model at all to the view.  Ok....  Whatever...

So now we get to the real problem.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Codes", 
    (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract , 
     new { style = "max-width: 600px;" })%>
```

Ok, let's ignore for a moment the fact that you have a WebForms closing code block indicator (%>) for some reason... The biggest problem here is that you're trying to cast `ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract` to a `List<SelectListItem>`, which is something it is not, and never was.

You converted the `List<MenuType>` to a `SelectList` which you then converted to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.  There was never any `List<SelectListItem>` involved.

So, the simple fix (besides rewriting your code to be sane) is to change your cast as such:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Codes", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract, 
     new { style = "max-width: 600px;" })
```

EDIT:

Since your MenuType does not contain the appropriate properties, you will have to modify your SelectList as such (Which I mention above).  FYI, ctypelist is already a list, no need to convert it to a list again... that's just silly.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = new SelectList(ctypelist, "Code", "Name");
```

Comment: have you test the code? i'm getting `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Comment: @AbuHamzah - is the value null?  See Edit above.

Comment: Yes the value is null

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Yes, that's because MenuType doesn't contain properties called Value and Text, so you have to specify the properties to use, see above edit.

Comment: After made the changes you have requested and now getting error new error on html page  `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Codes'.`

Comment: @AbuHamzah - that means your List of items is still null.  Make sure your query is returning items.

Comment: my query is returning items i see that when i do debug... this is driving me crazy.

Comment: @AbuHamzah - at this point, I have no idea what your current code looks like.. so it's hard to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I have posted this answer without knowledge of what variables your MenuType Class  has. Please add to your question and I will edit this answer according to youe MenuType Class

All Dropdowns are a collection of Value and Text Pairs.

```
<select>
<option value=1>TEXT 1</option>
<option value=2>TEXT 2</option>
<option value=3>TEXT 3</option>
</select>
```

You have a list of `List<MenuType>`, Which values from the MenuType do you want to display in the DropDown List?

Assuming you have this as MenuType.cs

```
public class MenuType
{
  public int MenuTypeId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

Your dropDown should be generated like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       Dictionary<int,string> ctypelist = db.ContractTypes.OrderBy(x => x.TypeOfContract).ToDictionary(s => s.MenuTypeId, s=> s.Name);


IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems = ctypelist.Select(s => new SelectListItem() { Value = s.Key.ToString(), Text = s.Value });

       ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract = selectListItems;
       return View();
    }
```

In View:

```
@{
var items = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.DropDownTypeOfContract;
}

    @Html.DropDownList("Codes", items , "Select Item")
```

Comment: getting error on first line 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' does not contain a definition for 'IEnumarable' and no extension method 'IEnumarable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: @AbuHamzah Spelling mistake by me: Correct: IEnumerable

Comment: I should have check the spelling first lol , another error complaining about Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.MenuType>' `

Comment: @AbuHamzah I have made a change

Comment: arggg.. `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Codes'.` is empy on html page

Comment: Try putting it in a ViewModel and pass to the View